# Подключить HTTP Модуль к SharePoint Online

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Есть Developre Site. К нему написан SharePoint Add-in (SharePoint hosted). Есть file input, и кнопка при нажатии на которую загруженный XML файл должен быть проверен по XSD-схеме. Для чего я добавил ASP Модуль со след. методом:(не уверен в его работоспособности, но вопрос не в этом)
Как подключить модуль? Доступа к Web.config в случае SP Online как я понял - просто нет.

```
public string ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

        {

        HttpPostedFile xml  = context.Request.Files[0];
        HttpPostedFile xsd = context.Request.Files[1];

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xml.InputStream);
        XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
        schemas.Add(XmlSchema.Read(xsd.InputStream, null));
        string msg = "";
        doc.Validate(schemas, (o, e) => {
            msg += e.Message + Environment.NewLine;
        });
        return "answer";
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И если не трудно - подскажите как в дальнейшем вызвать этот метод.

Comment: У меня закрадывается подозрение, что в SharePoint hosted приложении серверная логика вообще не подразумевается.Ни контроллера, ни доступа к web.config для регистрации модулей.

Comment: Вроде можно было sandbox-решения раньше загружать в содержимое сайта, сейчас кажется только Rest API поддерживается. Разберетесь, напишите, тоже интересно. Кстати на днях вышел SharePoint FrameWork - https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part Жалко пока только превью версия. Я еще не изучала, но разработку должно облегчить

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам подойдет вариант использования SharePoint Add-In (Provider-hosted). Более подробно про этот тип приложений можно прочитать [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381.aspx).